# ASUS X55A Laptop Bought with Win 8 but upgraded to Win 8.1

Tags: windows, updates

I am trying to get my regular *Windows Updates* done and repeatedly am met after being told to restart with *"Failure Configuring Windows Updates - Undoing Changes"*. The problem seems to go by the code **80246010**. And I am having a hard time getting a fix. Can anyone help?

Comment: I was able to find a [solution](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-error-80246008#1TC=windows-7) to your problem by doing a search on the error code.

Comment: **80246010 = WU_E_DM_DOWNLOADSANDBOXNOTFOUND** (*The sandbox directory for the downloaded update was not found*). I need the log files from C:\Windows\Logs\CBS to see more details.

Comment: I'm really thick when it comes to computers so thanks for answering me. What is it I do now - click on that word solution and follow the steps? Cheers for your time Ramhound.